# Python Read data from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

i have a program in Python that reads the data from a csv and i have 2 questions.

1. Lets say in the file i have data from yeah 1990 to 2020. What command can i use to only get the years from 2000 +?
2. Lets say the Dates in the file have this format '2000-12-02' how can i add it to a list because i think they are string at the moment and i cannot make the predict because i need strings.

The code i will put here has no corelation with the questions, it is just so that you can see the imports and stuff i use.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model


regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

df = pd.read_csv("net_monthly_average_earnings.csv")

print(df.head())

X = df[['Year']]
y = df[['Earnings']]

regr.fit(X, y)
earnings_predict = regr.predict(X)
plt.plot(X, y, 'o')
plt.plot(X, earnings_predict)

X_future = np.array(range(2021, 2030))
X_future = X_future.reshape(-1, 1)
future_predict = regr.predict(X_future)
plt.plot(X_future, future_predict, 'o')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Earning')
plt.title('Average salary in Romania + future predictions')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'], df['month'] = df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month
df
```

You can use "if" statement to only get the years you want.
In your case for example -

```
if X>2000:
    print(X)
```

Or you can use SQL to SELECT the years you wish to get in the DB(after creating init function)

```
def year_select(self,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP):
    self.cur.execute("SELECT YEAR IF>2000")
```

To put the dates in a list:

```
import pandas as pd

start = '2015-08-01' #YYY-MM-DD
end = '2020-07-06'

pd.date_range(start, end)

# to start from today

pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.today(), end)
```

Comment: No problem mate!